# Is there any danger in using a 12V 3A adapter with a device that ships with a 12V 1A?

Tags: amplifier, amperage

I've always heard an adapter's amperage being higher isn't an issue as long as the voltage and polarity match .

In audio, you get more head room (better sound at higher levels) if more power is available when the voltage demands it. This is proven even by using thicker cables on the AC side of things in my experience as a mastering engineer.

Is there any chance of frying gear with a substantially higher amperage than the advertised amperage of the unit?

My immediate goal is to use a 12V 3A adapter to replace a 12V 1A adapter that shipped with my class A tube mic pre to improve its low end and headroom.

Please avoid any skeptical responses on the impact on sound. I'm just trying to ensure I don't create any danger for the mic pre. Again, my understanding is that there is no threat.

If this safe, what constitutes an unsafe ratio of amps?

Thank you.

Comment: Great, but is there a limit to how many amps you can supply? Seems like 3A is no problem. But what about a 5A for a device shipping with 1A adapter?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any chance of frying gear with a substantially higher amperage than the advertised amperage of the unit?

No. A device only draws as much current as it needs. No more, no less. The rating on the supply is simply saying that it can deliver *up to* 3 amps as needed, meaning a circuit designed for a 1 amp supply will run on it without a problem. You could hook up a 12V 50A supply and the device will still draw less than 1 amp.

I suggest you read up on what current actually is. It sounds like you don't have a very strong grasp of the basic concepts of electricity.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought. I am simply nervous about blowing my gear. I am not an electronics expert. Even in the audio community, there is gross ignorance about how current affects sound.

Comment: Indeed there is, and this gross misunderstanding or ignorance of electronics is what leads to the whole "audiophile" snake-oil garbage.

Comment: @Jer DEFINITELY read Olin Lanthrop's answer in the linked question. It should really improve your understanding.

Comment: Yup. Read it. Understand it. Was just overly concerned about my gear.